# Sharepoint site properties

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss

I have to write a console application to access a sharepoint site using sharepoint dll. The site has some custom property set and the documentation available only tells the following.

> The key ContentTypeResources.<property key name here> is used to
>   retrieve the <property name> property.

Can anyone tell me how to access this property in code? web.AllProperties[""] does not have this key name. Is there something else?
Thanks in advance.

P.S: The site creation wizard is modified in this template and this property is saved on site creation.

Answer (score 0):

Check also web.Properties. May be it is there where the value is put in your wizard. If still no result I advise you to ensure to use the web.Properties in your wizard.